# Python: Create video out of processed images

Tags: python, opencv, video

i have a video where the front view of a car was recorded. The file is an .mp4 and i want to process the single images so i can extract more information (Objects, Lane Lines etc.). The problem is, when i want to create a video out of the processed files, i get an error. Here is what i have done so far:

1. Opened the video with cv2.VideoCapture() - Works fine
2. Saved the single frames of the video with cv2.imwrite() - Works fine
3. Creating a video out of single frames with cv2.VideoWriter() - Works fine
4. Postprocessing the video with cv2.cvtColor(), cv2.GaussianBlur() and cv2.Canny() - Works fine
5. Creating a video out of the processed images - Does not work.

Here is the code i used:

```
enter code here
def process_image(image):
    gray = functions.grayscale(image)
    blur_gray = functions.gaussian_blur(gray, 5)
    canny_blur = functions.canny(blur_gray, 100, 200)

    return canny_blur

process_on =0
count =0

video= cv2.VideoWriter("output.avi", cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"MJPG"), 10, (1600, 1200))

vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture('input.mp4')
success,image = vidcap.read()

success = True
while success:
  processed = process_image(image)
  video.write(processed)
```

This is the error i get:

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (img.cols == width && img.rows == height*3) in cv::mjpeg::MotionJpegWriter::write, file D:\Build\OpenCV\opencv-3.2.0\modules\videoio\src\cap_mjpeg_encoder.cpp, line 834
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "W:/Roborace/03_Information/10_Data/01_Montreal/camera/right_front_camera/01_Processed/Roborace_CAMERA_create_video.py", line 30, in 
>       video.write(processed)
>   cv2.error: D:\Build\OpenCV\opencv-3.2.0\modules\videoio\src\cap_mjpeg_encoder.cpp:834: error: (-215) img.cols == width && img.rows == height*3 in function cv::mjpeg::MotionJpegWriter::write

My suggestion is: The normal images have 3 dimensions because of the RGB-color field. The processed images are only having one dimension. How can i adjust this in the cv2.VideoWriter function.

Thanks for your help

Comment: On StackOverflow, it's customary to upvote answers you find helpful (that's the little upwards pointing triangle next to the answer). Also, if it's an answer to your question and you deem it the best one, there's a little checkmark that let's you "accept" it.

Answer (score 3):

The `VideoWriter()` class *only* writes color images, not grayscale images *unless* you are on Windows, which it looks like you might be judging from the paths in your output. On Windows, you can pass the optional argument `isColor=0` or `isColor=False` to the `VideoWriter()` constructor to write single-channel images. Otherwise, the simple solution is to just stack your grayscale frames into a three-channel image (you can use `cv2.merge([gray, gray, gray])` and write that.

From the [`VideoWriter()` docs](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/videoio/doc/reading_and_writing_video.html#videowriter):

> **Parameters:**
>
> **isColor** – If it is not zero, the encoder will expect and encode color frames, otherwise it will work with grayscale frames (the flag is currently supported on Windows only).

So by default, `isColor=True` and the flag cannot be changed on a non-Windows system. So simply doing:

```
video.write(cv2.merge([processed, processed, processed])
```

should patch you up. Even though the Windows variant allows writing grayscale frames, it may be better to use this second method for platform independence.

---

Also as [Zindarod mentions in the comments below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46526157/python-create-video-out-of-processed-images/46526212?noredirect=1#comment80006934_46526212) there are a number of other possible issues with your code here. I'm assuming you've pasted modified code that you weren't actually running here, or that you would have modified otherwise...if that's the case, please only post [minimal, *complete, and verifiable*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code examples.

First and foremost, your loop has no end condition, so it's indefinite. Secondly, you're hard-coding the frame size but `VideoWriter()` does not simply resize the images to that size. You must provide the size of the frame that you will pass into the `VideoWriter()`. Either resize the frame to the same size before writing to be sure, or create your `VideoWriter` using the frame size as defined in your `VideoCapture()` device (using the [`.get()` methods](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/videoio/doc/reading_and_writing_video.html#videocapture-get) for the frame size properties).

Additionally, you're reading only the first frame outside the loop. Maybe that was intentional, but if you want to process each frame of the video, you'll need to of course read them in a loop, process them, and then write them.

Lastly you should have some better error catching in your code. For e.g., see the [OpenCV "Getting Started with Video" Python tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html#saving-a-video). The "Saving a Video" section has the proper checks and balances: run the loop `while` the video capture device is opened, and process and write the frame only if the `frame` was read properly; then once it is out of frames, the `.read()` method will return `False`, which will allow you to break out of the loop and then close the capture and writer devices. Note the ordering here---the `VideoCapture()` device will still be "opened" even when you've read the last frame, so you need to close out of the loop by checking the contents of the frame.

Comment: There are a number of other ambiguities in his code, please address them in your answer. For example the frame size must match the size provided to the constructor, `VideoWriter` class does not automatically resize the frame to match the ctor. Also, he is writing frames in a loop, but reading the frames outside the loop.

Comment: @Zindarod sounds good, I did. I didn't include those suggestions originally as the OP listed a set of working actions, so I assumed OP was probably using this correctly but just pasted a bad example. However it's possible I'm wrong, and it's also worth writing about if others stumble upon the question, so thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Add `isColor=False` argument to the `VideoWriter`.

Adjusting `VideoWriter` this way will solve the issue.

Code:

```
video= cv2.VideoWriter("output.avi", cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"MJPG"), 10, (1600, 1200), isColor=False)
```